# What becomes of an array of integers when you offset the starting address in MIPS?

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips

If you have a word array in MIPS consisting of numbers (*5, 3, 0, 19*) that has a starting address in, let's say, **$t1**, and I add *4* to **$t1** (the starting address) I understand that **0($t1)** would now contain *3* instead of *5*. However, would the actual contents of the array change? As in would the array still be (*5, 3, 0, 19*) or would it now be (*3, 0, 19*) because i added to the starting address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`addiu $t1, $t1, 4`](http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html) doesn't change the contents of memory.

Just like in C, `int *p = array; p+=4;` doesn't change the array.